# Redis sort a list based on another list

Tags: list, sorting, redis

So I have two lists in Redis:

```
valuelist
1) value1
2) value2
3) value3

rowlist
1) 1
2) 2
3) 3
```

What I would like to be able to do is move the indices in rowlist based on the sorting of valuelist. For example, if I sort valuelist DESC then the new list would be:

```
valuelist
1) value3
2) value2
3) value1
```

But I would also like the rowlist indices to mimic the changes in the valuelist indices so rowlist would look like:

```
rowlist
1) 3
2) 2
3) 1
```

Is there a way to do this?  I have looked at the weight sorting capabilities of Redis, but was wondering what is the best way to do this besides creating key value pairs to use as weights.

Thanks

Comment: What is the real world application? Maybe there is a better way or a better suited data structure in redis for this.

Comment: The idea is that rowlist is a list of Row IDs and valuelist is a column in a table. When I do a sort on that particular columns values, I want the Row ID values to also sort accordingly.  I then use the sorted Row ID list to grab the other column values in that Row, essentially sorting the table by that initial column.

Comment: How do you sort the first list? Are there any duplicates?

Comment: I sort the first list by using SORT ALPHA DESC or ASC and there can be duplicates.